# What is the correct type for React Click Event?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I want to use a type for my event handler instead of using type any,
Can anyone help me with this,please?
here is the code I'm trying to refactor:

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  const handleBtnClick = (e: any) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    //**Some Code**
  }
  return <CustomButton onClick={handleBtnClick} />
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you create a `<button>` and hover over `onClick` prop you'll get the type in the tooltip:

[image]

In your example code, you are creating a custom button so the types depend on the implementation of that component.

Comment: This isn't exactly universally applicable - I assume you're using an editor like Visual Studio Code or Webstorm - but it's good advice nonetheless, provided whoever is reading this is using an editor like that

Comment: @TKoL the screenshot is actually taken from stackblits - a browser-based editor. Typescript dev tools are available in practically every editor/ide since great dev tools are one of the main reasons people choose this language.

Comment: this will vary in my case I was submitting the `form` the ***typehint*** for `event` would be something like this<br> ```(e : React.FormEvent)```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 19):

For typings you should have TypeScript where you can do this:

```
const handleBtnClick = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => { ... }
```

Please refer to this:
https://fettblog.eu/typescript-react/events/

Of course, you could try it without TypeScript but is not worth it.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the type you are looking for is React.MouseEvent, a [synthetic event](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#mouse-events) provided by React.  More info and examples may be found [here](https://fettblog.eu/typescript-react/events/).

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a reasonable explanation:
https://rjzaworski.com/2018/10/typescript-event-handlers

React.MouseEvent